# Refresh a div tag once

Tags: javascript, ajax, html, refresh

Just looking for a way to refresh the content of a `DIV` tag once. For example, lets say your markup is:

```
<body>
<div id="RefreshOnce">
<?php include('loading.php') ?>
</div>
</body>
```

I know how to update the content of that DIV tag using a Javascript with ajax to refresh it multiple times to say another file called content.php. I can't seem to figure out how to just make it refresh one time.

The function is basic: div loads a loader page with cool loading image, then waits 2 seconds and loads the actual content once.

Comment: Could you please try and restate the problem. Your current wording makes the problem very unclear. You may also want to correct your example. Presumably "RefreshOnce" is a id and should be between quotes? Why mix in a PHP include in your example?

Comment: First, `<div=RefreshOnce>` makes no sense. I think you meant `<div id="RefreshOnce">`. Second, you will have to clarify what you mean by "refresh". If you are using AJAX to replace the content of the div, then you just need to wait for the response from the AJAX call and then set the content of the div using something like `document.getElementById("RefreshOnce").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, load the div content from one resource and then reload it from another resource, after some time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(function() {
      $('#fooDiv').load( 'a.html' );
      setTimeout( reloadDiv, 5000 );
  });

  function reloadDiv() {
     $('#fooDiv').load( 'b.html' );
  }

</script>
```

Comment: Awesome man, this worked wonderfully. You nailed it on the dot for what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Use these two javascript functions:

- setTimeout() - executes a code some time in the future
- clearTimeout() - cancels the setTimeout()

You can lookup examples here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp

You just place an AJAX request in your function, and clear the timeout just after. Job done:=)